# How to backup /user/home with some requirements?

Tags: backup, read

I'm currently studying scripting and I need to create an script to back up the /user/home using `.bz2` compression. My teacher wants the person running the script to select the user to backup and the method of compression. I've created a very simple script, but I would like to tune it up a bit.

This is what I need:

```
#/bin/bash
#Choose user to backup
#choose compression method.
```

Final results of script:

```
user_20151126.tar.bz2
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n Enter a User Name for the back:
read UserName

echo -n Enter the compression method:
read CompressionMethod

tar -jcvf /var/tmp/$UserName_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.$CompressionMethod /home

chmod 777 /var/tmp/$UserName_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.$CompressionMethod

echo "Nightly Backup Successful: $(date)" >> /var/tmp_backup.log
```

My results:

```
20151126.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following changes and bug fixes:

```
#!/bin/bash

#first we test whether we have enough input parameters
if [ "x$1" == "x" ] || [ "x$2" == "x" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 <user_name> <compression method bz2|gz|Z>"
fi

#test if we have read access to the users home directory
if [ ! -r /home/$1 ]; then
  echo "could not read /home/${1}"
  exit 1
fi

#now we parse the compression method and set the correct tar flag for it
case $2 in
  "bz2")
  flag=j;;
  "gz")
  flag=z;;
  "Z")
  flag=Z;;
  *)
  echo "unsupported compression method valid methods are <bz2|gz|Z>"
  exit 1;;
esac

#we need to enclose variable names not followed by whitespace in {} otherwise the letters following the variable name will be recognized as part of the variable name
tar -${flag}cvf /var/tmp/${1}_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.$2 /home/${1}/

chmod 777 /var/tmp/${1}_$(date +%Y%m%d).tar.$2

echo "Nightly Backup Successful: $(date)" #>> /var/tmp/backup.log
```

the script is called like this:

```
backup.sh user bz2
```

if you want the user name and compression method to be entered interactively, use your code that does this and replace ${1} with ${UserName} (and $1 with $USerName) and ${2} with ${CompressionMethod}

good luck with your homework.